# Blurred Firefox and Thunderbird Icons

Tags: unity, firefox, display, icons, thunderbird

I recently connected my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to an external display. Since then, only my Firefox and Thunderbird Icons are appearing blurred. After a lot of searching, this is what I have gathered so far.

a) My launcher icon size is set to an even value (odd values having blurred icons is a known defect for Ubuntu)

b) When I removed the display settings by running rm ~/.config/monitors.xml in the command line and then restarted, the icons where working properly for the first few seconds. Then they reverted back to their previous blurred state.

Please help.

Comment: Well seems like you are not alone, comment here to reactivate the thread https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1531345

Comment: Done. I had commented some time back too. The guy just above your comment.

Comment: Can you please confirm that after quitting thunderbird the firefox and thunderbird icons becomes normal?

Comment: No they do not. As I mentioned in b), when I removed the display settings by running rm ~/.config/monitors.xml in the command line and then restarted, the icons where working properly for the first few seconds. Then they reverted back to their previous blurred state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just solved the problem by getting into ".thunderbird" directory and simply deleting the files named as "thunderbird.png" and "firefox.png". There were 22x22 icons in the apps directory of ".thunderbird".

To do that, go to home directory and in there get inside the directory named as ".thunderbind". Inside the ".thunderbird" directory,

`find | grep "firefox"`  for finding "firefox.png" and then:

`rm the_output_address_of_find_command`

Repeat the same thing for "thunderbird.png" file.